# Logout OnClientClick not working with Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, sweetalert

Sweeetalert not working like confirm box ,it does not wait for callbackfunction

When i click on logout it logs out without waiting for sweetalert yes no confirmation

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUserlogout" Text="Logout" 
                               OnClick="btnUserlogout_Click"
                               OnClientClick="return UserDeleteConfirmation();"  />


function UserDeleteConfirmation() {
           return  swal({
            title: "Are you sure to Logout? ",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        });
}
```

Also i tried with this Code

```
function UserlogoutConfirmation() {
        // return confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?");
       return  swal({
            title: "Are you sure to submit Project? ",
            text: " Once submitted, You will not be able to make any change!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
       }, function (con) {
           if (con) {
               return true
           } else {
               return false
           }
       });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Promise. Sweet Alert returns a promise you can react on.
see this example from the official Sweet Alert documentation from Github (https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert)

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Are you sure that you want to leave this page?",
  icon: "warning",
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then(willDelete => {
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
  }
});
```

alternative you can use async. this is also explained in the documentation on Github.

To come back to your code if you return the swal function you can just check if the user confirmed like this:

```
function UserDeleteConfirmation() {
           return  swal({
            title: "Are you sure to Logout? ",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        });
}

UserDeleteConfirmation().then((isClicked) => {
    //isClicked is true if the button is clicked
}
```